# Remove menu item dashboard for a unique user

Tags: wp-admin, actions, admin-menu

I want to disable access to some pages like "Themes" or "Plugins" for my client (just his ID) and try to do it in the `functions.php` with this script:

**EDIT :** WORKING CODE :

```
function hide_menu() {
 global $current_user;
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 // echo "user:".$user_id;   // Use this to find your user id quickly

    if($user_id == '2') {
        remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=ozy_fonts' );
        remove_submenu_page( 'index.php', 'update-core.php' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the menu pages isn't the right approach. You should be modifying the user's role or capabilities so that they don't have *permission* to modify themes or plugins. Then the menus won't appear and they won't be able to get around it by manually entering the URL.  Do a search for "wordpress modify user capabilities" and you'll find dozens of resources for achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already use User Role Editor but i can't disable access to these pages. When a user is an admin (and i need my client to be an admin) you can't disable access to plugin pages etc... :/

Comment: It doesn't work because wp_get_current_user() does not return an ID but an object. Try get_current_user_id()

Comment: Thanks ! Dit a lot of modifications and now i have a working code !